# Prevent exterior outswing door from swinging open fast

Tags: doors, wind

I have an outswing exterior patio door that I need to prevent from blowing open fast when the door is open. I've left the door open a few times to quickly grab something in the backyard and the wind has blown the door all the way open and bent the hinges. This has happened to me on more than one occasion.

Is there something other than one of those bulky door closers that I could use to soften the door opening or prevent the hinges from taking the brunt of the force? I don't need the door to automatically close but I need it to not swing open very fast and bend the hinges.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen hinges that were sensitive to speed. is it not rather the extent that the door opens that is causing the problem?

Comment: Perhaps a less-bulky door spring, but dismissing a door closer out of hand seems a bit rash given that it would actually address your problem quite effectively.  But, for you, for extra money, they do make "concealed" door closers. I also see a less expensive "concealed door stop" which has a spring to cushion the blow at the end of travel, for less money (no closer function, from a quick look.)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to put a door stop to prevent the door from swinging open enough that it breaks the hinges. It'll still blow open but the strain on the hinges will be reduced to below damage levels.

This can be as simple as a rock or brick on the ground that the door will collide with before it can reach self-damage territory. As long as it's heavy enough to not move it should suffice. Prettier options for stops exist.

There are also wall mounted stops which jut out a bit and reduce the strain compared to bending over the frame.